# IdentityUser: "Name cannot be null or empty"

Tags: asp.net, identity

I've been trying to inherit IdentityUser to make my own class which uses Identity and still writes to my database and I keep getting this error when I try to call my registration post method:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "$id": "2",
        "": [
            "Name cannot be null or empty."
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried number of things, but nothing works.For example when I try to set UserName field of IdentityUser it says it's impossible because it doesn't exist in the context.
The important thing to mention would be that I am using ADO.NET database first model for the account :)

This is the class:

```
public partial class Account :IdentityUser
    {
        public Account()
        {
            this.Families = new HashSet<Family>();
        }

        public long idAccount { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Family> Families { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my authentication repository class:

```
public class AuthRepository :IDisposable
    {
        private DAKPAKEntities _ctx;

        private UserManager<Account> _userManager;

        public AuthRepository()
        {
            _ctx = new DAKPAKEntities();
            _userManager = new UserManager<Account>(new UserStore<Account>(_ctx));
        }

        public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(Account userModel)
        {
            Account user = new Account
            {

                firstName = userModel.firstName,
                lastName = userModel.lastName,
                email=userModel.email
            };


            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user,userModel.password);

            return result;
        }
```

}

And this is the controller that calls the repository:

```
// POST api/Account/Register


     [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(Account userModel)
        {
            IdentityResult result = await _repo.RegisterUser(userModel);

            IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

            if (errorResult != null)
            {
                return errorResult;
            }



 return Ok();
    }
```

I am new to this, and am out of options to try. I did almost everything that's usually suggested for this type of error, please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't done everything that is required in order to change the way ASPNet Identity stores the user information in the database.

Suggest you start here: [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity#user)